# whole page refreshes upon clicking drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have a gridview, textboxes, drop downs inside update panel, it works good but problem is that when i click any drop down than it changes scrolls back the whole page to top and refreshes it, why ?

Code:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updGridViewSMS" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <label><b>Search By Date Range</b></label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDateFrom" runat="server" Text="From"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>                      
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderFromDate" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtFromDate" runat="server">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtFromDate" Display="None" ErrorMessage="" 
                            ForeColor="Red" >
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDateTo" runat="server" Text="To"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderToDate" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtToDate" runat="server">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtToDate" Display="None" ErrorMessage="" 
                            ForeColor="Red" >
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearchByDate"  CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                    ClientIDMode="Static"  OnClick="btnSearchByDate_Click" />
        <asp:ValidationSummary
         HeaderText="Requires Date Range:"
         DisplayMode="SingleParagraph"
         EnableClientScript="true"
         ForeColor="Red"
         runat="server" ID="ValidationSummary1"/>
       <label runat="server" id="lblSelectionMessage" style="color:navy; font-size:12px; font-style:italic" visible="false">
           Please select one validity dropdown at a time
       </label>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" BorderColor="#333333"  Width="650px" OnRowDataBound="GridViewSmsComplaints_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging" >
           <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sms ID" DataField="ID" /> 
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recieving Date" DataField="RecievingDate" />  
                <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ToMobileNo" DataField="ToMobileNo" />  --%>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Incoming No" DataField="FromMobileNo" /> 
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Complaint" DataField="Message" >   
                 <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Valid?">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                   <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint"  runat="server" />--%>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsComplaint" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlIsComplaint_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Invalid" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Valid" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                   </asp:DropDownList>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>    

    <br />
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlBoxesDropDowns" runat="server">
    <label>Complainant</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComplainant" runat="server" CssClass="textField_width"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValdiatorComplainant" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtComplainant" ErrorMessage="Complainant is Required" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="Complaints">Complainant is Required
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <label style="width:400px">Region</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegions" runat="server" CssClass="DropDown_Width" Width="147px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRegions_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True"  AutoPostBack="true" >
      <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Selected="True">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValidatorRegions" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="ddlRegions" ErrorMessage="Region is Required" InitialValue="-1"
     ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Complaints">Region is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <label style="width:400px">District</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDistricts" runat="server" CssClass="DropDown_Width" Width="147px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDistricts_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValidatorDistricts" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="ddlDistricts" ErrorMessage="Region is Required" InitialValue="-1"
     ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Complaints">District is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <label>PoliceStations</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPoliceStations" runat="server" Width="147px" CssClass="DropDown_Width">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValidatorPoliceStations" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="ddlPoliceStations" ErrorMessage="Police Station is Required" InitialValue="-1"
     ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Complaints">Police Station is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <label>Priority</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPriority" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Top" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Normal" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <br />
        <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="60000" ID="RefreshSmsComplaints" OnTick="RefreshSmsComplaints_Tick" />
      </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RefreshSmsComplaints" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSendSms" ValidationGroup="Complaints"  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success"  
        OnClick="btnSendSms_Click" Text="Send Sms" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnGenerateReport"  CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Generate Report" 
                    ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnGenerateReport_Click" />
```

Comment: please check on your dropdown properties. if autopostback is true change it to false

Comment: you can see that in code instead of asking me.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegions" runat="server" CssClass="DropDown_Width" Width="147px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRegions_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True"  AutoPostBack="true" >
    CHANGE TO AutoPostBack="false"

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDistricts" runat="server" CssClass="DropDown_Width" Width="147px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDistricts_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    CHANGE TO AutoPostBack="false"

Answer (score 0):

the autopostback="true" statement causes this to happen. This is required is you want a server side event to run after you update the drop down list. If you want to prevent a postback, and thus a page refresh you should remove the autopostback="true" statement. Doing so will prevent the 'OnSelectedIndexChanged' event from being thrown. In order to solve this you can create a javascript client side function equivalent for this event.

Serverside events and client side events are two different types of events. If you do know know what is meant with this, you should do some research into this.

Answer (score 0):

Set the update mode as conditional for the update panel containing DropDownList and set ChildrenAsTriggers = false. If you are updating any values in the dropdownlist ChildrenAsTriggers = false does not refresh the page.